# Date trash was last emptied bash

Tags: terminal, bash, trash

I'm trying to find out at what date and time the trash was last emptied. Would it be the date modified of the least recently modified file? Does moving it to the trash count as modifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the last emptied date is not stored, it does update the last modification date. Therefore, providing you have not added anything to a trash since, the last modification date of each .Trashes will be the last time that trash was emptied.